# Memory use with Java JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, memory-leaks, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I have a Java (Swing) data logging application writing text to a `JTextArea` inside a `JScrollPane`. The applications appends text to the `JTextArea` and it scrolls up accordingly. There is only 5 lines of text in the viewable area and it would be acceptable if the user were only able to scroll back a 100 or so lines, but it appears to me that the amount of memory consumed will continue to grow without limit.

Is there anything I can do to limit the number of lines retained or otherwise limit the amount of memory used?

Answer (score 2):

The scroll pane has nothing to do with this. You could limit the data held by the PlainDocument that is used by the JTextArea. I think that a DocumentFilter could be used for this purpose.

**Edit 1**
Here's a *simple* DocumentFilter version of camickr's code (Rob: sorry for the out and out theft!).

```
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class LimitLinesDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter {
   private int maxLineCount;

   public LimitLinesDocumentFilter(int maxLineCount) {
      this.maxLineCount = maxLineCount;
   }

   @Override
   public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string,
            AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
      super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);

      removeFromStart(fb);
   }

   @Override
   public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text,
            AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
      super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);

      removeFromStart(fb);
   }

   private void removeFromStart(FilterBypass fb) {
      Document doc = fb.getDocument();
      Element root = doc.getDefaultRootElement();
      while (root.getElementCount() > maxLineCount) {
         removeLineFromStart(doc, root);
      }
   }

   private void removeLineFromStart(Document document, Element root) {
      Element line = root.getElement(0);
      int end = line.getEndOffset();

      try {
         document.remove(0, end);
      } catch (BadLocationException ble) {
         ble.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

}
```

And the code to test it on:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.PlainDocument;

public class LimitLinesDocumentFilterTest {
   private static void createAndShowUI() {
      int rows = 10;
      int cols = 30;
      JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea(rows , cols );
      PlainDocument doc = (PlainDocument)textarea.getDocument();
      int maxLineCount = 9;
      doc.setDocumentFilter(new LimitLinesDocumentFilter(maxLineCount ));

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Limit Lines Document Filter Test");
      frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(textarea));
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowUI();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: @camickr: Rob, sorry for the out-and-out theft of your code! /Pete

Comment: @SteveJP: the down-side of using a DocumentFilter is that each Document can have only one filter (as far as I understand it).

Comment: +1, Pete, no problem, thats what examples are for, to suggest/try different approaches. Yep, a Document can only have a single filter. For what its worth I try to address this issue in "Chaining Document Filters" (http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/10/18/chaining-document-filters/).

Comment: Thank you Hovercraft, you have gone to quite a lot of trouble. I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there anything I can do to limit the number of lines retained

See: [Limit Lines in Document](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/15/limit-lines-in-document/).

Comment: Yep, a DocumentListener will work too (1+), but then you will need to use camickr's trick of updating the document in a Runnable queued on the EDT in order to allow the listener to modify the Document.

Comment: Thanks camickr - I'll try your method. Appreciate the response. Steve